# Android using JSON Objects

Tags: android, arrays, listview, textview

I'm trying to populate a ListView with various objects obtained from a RESTApi.

To test if the connection, and the objects are actually recieved, I invoke this method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONArray users = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(1);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, user.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            jsonList = users;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The Toast does show me the name of the current object, but whenever I try to populate my ListView, I get a NullPointerException.

I made a TextView to test if the JSON is actually there aswell, but here I get another NullPointerException:

```
textView.setText(user.getString("name"));
```

Why does it give me a NullPointer here, when the JSONObject works fine in the Toast?

Comment: Post your ListView codes and also logcat output please

Comment: Parsing the JSON doesn't seem the problem. Are the XML-objects (ListView, TextView, ..) properly initialized?

Comment: put your json example and the listview handling code

Comment: Right now I'm talking about the TextView and not the ListView (JSON: `[{"name":"Christian Haase","_id":"54eda37aa4e01feebaf9c66a","__v":0},{"name":"Line Mungaard","_id":"54edde9ba4e01feebaf9c66b","__v":0}]`)

Comment: Are you sure that your `textView` (or for that matter also the specific `ListView` object) are at that point *not* null? Seems like the most obvious thing, if you put your `setText` method at the same place where the `Toast` shows a valid value. (The only other thing that comes to mind would be that your json results might differ from time to time, and thus sometimes working sometimes not.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as your code seems 
You are accessing the first element of users object
You have to specify list view's first index as well, 
you are accessing 1st element and passing to the whole `listview`
Please follow the basic programming of Listview 
[http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/](http://Follow%20the%20tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Bean class with getters and setters then populate the Bean with JSON data and use it as the data source to your listView adapter!